# How to set ppp0 interface

Tags: networking, ppp

I'm trying to create ppp0 interface. I have written in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet ppp
provider international
```

But when I try "sudo ifconfig ppp0 up" I get:

> ppp0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

I have restarted my PC and network manager. I have never used ppp interfaces so I'm probably missing some previous basic configuration. How can I set up a ppp0 device?